# Is it possible to user Solr facets with Solr dynamic fields?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, solr

I am about to use Solr'd Dynamic Fields for the first time but my requirements state that those fields have to be facetable. I did quite a lot of googling and doc reading but I can't find a place that either confirms or denies the allegation :)

Does anyone here know?

Thanks in advance!
Andre

Comment: Can you explain how? The below question says "No" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512392/facet-dynamic-fields-with-apache-solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can facet on dynamic fields just fine.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio! I have not had a chance to test this yet but I will have to in a couple of weeks and I will mark your answer as correct once I confirm it.