# Solr multi-select faceting with dynamic fields?

Tags: indexing, solr, facet, faceted-search

I'm working with some dynamic attributes in a product catalog, indexed under one field (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529566/2759883)). A simple example would look like this:

```
{id: 1,  DYN_ATT:Color||Green,  DYN_ATT:Size||Small}
{id: 2,  DYN_ATT:Color||Red,    DYN_ATT:Size||Small}
{id: 3,  DYN_ATT:Color||Green,  DYN_ATT:Size||Small}
{id: 4,  DYN_ATT:Color||Red,    DYN_ATT:Size||Large}
```

However, it seems to be impossible to enable multi-select as if these are all different facets.

For example, say the user selects the `Green` Color facet in the UI:

```
[ ]Red
[ ]Green
----------
[ ]Small
[ ]Large
```

The resulting facets should show all possible values for `Color` (to allow the user to select `Red` OR `Green`. But should filter the `Size` facet based on `Green` being selected in another (logical) facet.

```
[ ]Red
[x]Green
----------
[ ]Small
```

Is there any way to do this?
I haven't found any answers and suspect a different approach may be needed.
Unfortunately the types of attributes in the data vary wildly.

Neither of these work:

```
fq={!tag=DYNTAG}DYN_ATT:"Color||Green"&facet.field={!ex=DYNTAG}DYN_ATT
```

This yields too many results for `Size`. A facet for `[ ]Large` should NOT be available, but would be returned. If the user selects it, the two filters would be disjoint and yield no results.

```
fq={!tag=DYNTAG}DYN_ATT:"Color||Green"&facet.field=DYN_ATT
```

This yields too few results, excluding `Red` from facets, so the user would NOT be able to multi-select on Color:

```
[x]Red
[x]Green
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to solve this problem.
It turns out the same `facet.field` may be reused with different tags, like this:

```
&facet=true
&fq={!tag=DYN}DYN_ATT:"Color||Green"
&facet.field=DYN_ATT
&facet.field={!ex=DYN key=DYN_ATT_OR}DYN_ATT
```

This yields two results for the `DYN_ATT` facet. Something like this:

```
"facet_fields": {
    "DYN_ATT": [
        // facets filtered based on fq
    ]
    "DYN_ATT_OR": [
        // facets unfiltered
    ]
```

Then I just had to use the `DYN_ATT` contents for the unselected facet results, and the `DYN_ATT_OR` facets for the selected facet results (those I want to allow OR-ing on, for multi-select).